# Session variable access with out session recreation

Tags: java, jsp, session

How to access a session variable with out session="true" tag  in a jsp page ..? or with out recreating session.?

Answer (score 0):

do you can catch your Request?

In your jsp page use:

```
<%
    Object obj = request.getSession().getAttribute("STRING");
%>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It would create a new session if none exists, you need to use `getSession(false)` and check for `null` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just use EL.

```
${sessionAttributeName}
```

It will only scan in session scope if the session is been created. See also [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29).

Or if you really insist in using old fashioned *scriptlets*, then just don't create session while attempting to access the attribute. You can do that by [`HttpServletRequest.getSession(boolean)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29) with `false`. It will return `null` when the session is not been created before.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session != null) {
    Object sessionAttribute = session.getAttribute("sessionAttributeName");
}
```